# Angular Jest test cases got failed after updating the aws-amplify version from 3.4.3 to 4.3.46

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, ts-jest, babel-jest, angular-jest

We are using aws-amplify for our page authentication after updating the aws-amplify package to the latest version few jest test cases got failed. I attached the below screenshot for reference. I added the **transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(aws-amplify)/)',]** but it doesn't help.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYbxp.png)

FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

C:\Users\gokulakrishnan.k\Angular App\events-kiosk\node_modules\@aws-sdk\client-lex-runtime-service\node_modules\uuid\dist\esm-browser\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  2 | import { Component, HostListener, Inject, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
  3 | import { Router } from '@angular/router';
> 4 | import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
    | ^
  5 | import { CommonMethods } from './common/utilities/common-methods';
  6 | import { BffService } from './providers/bff.service';
  7 |

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/StandardRetryStrategy.js:6:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/AdaptiveRetryStrategy.js:6:33)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/index.js:4:22)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/LexRuntimeServiceClient.js:9:28)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/LexRuntimeService.js:9:35)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service/dist-cjs/index.js:5:22)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-amplify/interactions/src/Providers/AWSLexProvider.ts:20:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-amplify/interactions/src/Providers/index.ts:13:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-amplify/interactions/src/Interactions.ts:21:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@aws-amplify/interactions/src/index.ts:13:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-amplify/src/index.ts:45:1)
  at Object.require (src/app/app.component.ts:4:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:4:1)
```

Our jest.config.js file
[jest.config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hwBe.png)

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec).+(ts)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts'],
  verbose: true,
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>"],
  globalSetup: "jest-preset-angular/global-setup",
};
```

Our app.module.ts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP3yV.png)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { BffService } from './providers/bff.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  validUser = false
  constructor(private bff : BffService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkUserStatus()
  }

  checkUserStatus(){
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user=>{
      this.bff.getUserPermission(user.attributes.email).subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this.validUser = res.validUser
        }
      })
      this.validUser = true;
    }).catch(error=>{
      Auth.federatedSignIn()
    })
  }

  logoutUser(){
    Auth.signOut({ global: true }).then().catch((error) => {
      console.log('error signing out: ', error);
    });
  }

}
```

I tried to add the transformIgnorePatterns but its not working. I need to resolve the issue with aws-amplify package version more than 3.4.3 because we are upgrading our Angular app to 17. If we are using the aws-amplify version 3.4.3 we are getting **graphql** error.

Comment: My dude, it takes 2 seconds to copy paste the text, please don't post code as images.